# Aggregate Sub-Document Ignoring Key Order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

test data:

```
    db.moretest.insert(
[
{ "title" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } },
{ "title" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } },
{ "title" : { "b" : 2, "a" : 1 } },
{ "title" : { "foo" : 42, "a" : 1 } },
]
)
```

I want to count how often a key occurs in "title", ignoring the order. E.g.  `{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }` and `{ "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }` should be treated the same.

However, this query doesn't produce the desired result:

```
db.moretest.aggregate(
   [
     { $group: { "_id": "$title", "count": { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
);
```

results in

```
{ "_id" : { "foo" : 42, "a" : 1 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, "count" : 2 }
```

But what I want is the following:

```
{ "_id" : { "foo" : 42, "a" : 1 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, "count" : 3 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB actually does consider such different order in object keys to indicate "uniqueness". For general "query" purposes, this is why the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) form exists, to specify the [path to keys at "depth"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) instead of an exact match format.

For the same reason, this also applies to aggregation. If you want the combination in any order, then your actually need to "force the order" to be consistent.

This is done in Modern releases [since MongoDB 3.4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#apr-21-2017) as:

```
db.moretest.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "title": { "$objectToArray": "$title" },
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$title" },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "title.k": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "title": { "$push": "$title" }    
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$arrayToObject": "$title" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }}
])
```

Which can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) in order to turn the "keys" into an "array", which can then be "sorted". The problem is that in order to do that you still need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array elements and apply a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) pipeline stage and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) back into an array before transforming back with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

But it does get the result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : 1.0,
        "b" : 2.0
    },
    "count" : 3.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : 1.0,
        "foo" : 42.0
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

Even if not very efficiently. So being able to sort the array in place would be better.

You "could" alternately decide which way to present `"title"` by testing for "specific keys", albeit in a very hacky way:

```
db.moretest.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$ifNull": [ "$title.b", false ] },
        "then": { "a": "$title.a", "b": "$title.b" },
        "else": "$title"
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }  
  }}
])
```

Which is the same and of course would actually "reorder" the keys of any object that did not meet the supplied conditions. It does however require some foreknowledge of what the keys in the target object actually are in order to supply the conditions. But it may be a viable option if your actual use case supported that being practical.

---

For other releases and somewhat more efficiently ( even if relying on JavaScript interpretation to do so ) is using `.mapReduce()`:

```
db.moretest.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(
      Object.keys(this.title).sort()
        .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr]: this.title[curr] }), {}),
      1
    );
  },
  function(key,values) { return Array.sum(values) },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which does more or less the same thing, but with it's own result set format:

```
"results" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 1.0,
            "b" : 2.0
        },
        "value" : 3.0
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 1.0,
            "foo" : 42.0
        },
        "value" : 1.0
    }
],
```

Comment: The first query works fine! Fortunately, the database is not that big and query runtime is fine. However, what exactly does `"title": { "$push": "$title" }`  do?

Comment: @user3648650 Best to read the manual and understand things. Missed links for [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) and of course [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Try running the aggregation "one stage at a time", i.e First just `$project` only. Then `$project` and `$unwind`, and so on until you added all the stages listed. Then you should clearly see what is happening and why.